# Abnormal battery behaviour when playing games

Tags: 16.04, laptop, battery

I'm having a really awkward problem with my battery using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Every time I play high-resource consuming games (for a notebook that is using the processor's integrated graphics card) the charge percentage drops to the floor suddenly (from reasonable percentages to zero just in a second).
I don't have a clue about what's causing this.

The real problem for me is not this, because I use the notebook plugged in when I'm playing, the problem is that even if the charger is connected (The AC adapter "Online" status was "Yes" every time this happened) the battery doesn't charge.

**Some details about my computer:**

- It's a TCL A7 4500
- Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit
- *Processor:* Intel® Core™ i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8
- *Graphics:* Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

[image: (Click to view) Screenshot of my notebook's battery charge graph]

Comment: Could be a problem with your charger, seems like the charger is not supplying enough power, so your laptop is using battery power as well - are you using the original charger that came with the laptop ? Does the same thing happen in Windows ?

Comment: @JonasCz Yep. The charger is the one that came with the notebook. Anyways it has a modification in the DC connector because I had problems with it in the past.
The thing is that this does ONLY happen when I'm playing.
Also, I really don't know if that happens in Windows; I don't have Windows anymore (since 2015).

Comment: @JonasCz Also, the problem is the power consumption/charge speed in some intervals: Look at the graph between 24m and 12m; the change is abrupt (insanely abrupt: it goes down and then up exponentially), there must be something wrong with the way that the system is measuring the remaining battery power.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what could be causing this, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry @JonasCz,  I may try a new charger soon. Thanks for the comments!